# image uploading and displaying

Tags: php, image, uploading

I am new for php. I want to store a selected image in a folder (name:uploads) and when the upload button is clicked i want to display the image on the same page. I tried with the below code, but i am getting error on echo statement.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP File Upload example</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="new.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
Select image :
<input type="file" name="file"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="Submit1"> <br/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit1']))
{  
    $filepath = "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    echo $filepath;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $filepath)) 
    {
        echo "<img src=".$filepath." height=200 width=300 />";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Error !!";
    }
} 
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
<form action="new.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

change to

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

and also make sure that you have **uploads** folder (with write permission) where this php script is placed

Comment: thanx for the reply, i tried this also <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">. But not working when i echo my echo $filepath; its showing . the things is if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $filepath)) 
{
echo "<img src=".$filepath." height=200 width=300 />";
} this is one is not working if any suggestion

Comment: I have tried your code it worked for me when i added **uploads** folder the scrip directory. For me image was successfully uploaded and shown on the screen (same page).

Comment: Yes bro its working, i have changed the folder permissions and now its fine.Thanx